# jQuery can't access elements loaded through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a little application written in PHP. The front-end uses jQuery and AJAX. At one point, jQuery loads some content in through AJAX. The problem is, it can't then access any of the elements it just loaded. Anyone know why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need more data than that, as jQuery most definitely can access data loaded through AJAX. Possibly have to wait half a second (use `setTimeout` ) before you can.

Comment: what would be the exact code to wait half a sec?

Comment: How can we tell what's wrong without seeing your code?

Comment: You don't need to wait a half a second if in the ajax call you have the success function set up.  this gets called when you have returned

Comment: I agree with @griegs. `setTimeout()` would almost definitely not be the solution to use.

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem! I know the element is in the page already because I can retrieve its attributes.  But I cannot alter or add attributes.

Answer (score 3):

@Ryan, in your jQuery are you trying to access the elements as fresh elements or are you expecting events to already be bound to the elements?

i ask because if you have say a span that has a click event attached to it, when you load a new one that new span won't have a click event yet.  you'll need to bind one or use i think the .live keyword to always have spans, even spans created later, bind to the same events.

It would help if you had a small sample of your html before, after and the jquery you are running so we can see and debug for you.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is typically synchronous, but AJAX calls are by default asynchronous.

The upshot is that if you're trying to access the data that was returned and added to the DOM directly after the AJAX call, it is likely that that code has run before the AJAX response was received. As such, it seems like the data is inaccessible.

The solution is to do your manipulations in the `success` callback to the AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some/path/to/data",
    success: function( data ) {
        // Add returned data to DOM
        //   and manipulate data as needed
    }
});

// Can't access returned data here because this code
//    has likely executed before the response was returned.
```